# Python Regex match numbers after words

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group, regex-negation

I am looking to match separately the numbers contained in the following type of string using regex:

```
https://www.pizza.com/word1/685185197419/word2/980054970331342/
```

output:

```
w1 = 685185197419
w2 = 980054970331342
```

I am using this expression but it does not work properly: `\word1(.*)[0-9]\/`

Comment: "*it does not work properly*" is not a helpful problem statement. What does it do? What did you *expect* it to do? [ask]

Comment: Just use `word1/(\d+)/word2/(\d+)` ? `re.findall(r"word1/(\d+)/word2/(\d+)", s)`

Comment: You could use an alternation to match any of the words, and then capture the digits in group 1 `/(?:word1|word2)/(\d+)(?=/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify where to find each digit sequences. Also, you can use named groups, which can match the variables you want at the end

```
s = "https://www.pizza.com/word1/685185197419/word2/980054970331342/"

r = re.match(r"^.*word1/(?P<w1>\d+)/word2/(?P<w2>\d+)/$", s)

w1 = r.group("w1")
w2 = r.group("w2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/jXvayv/1):

```
(?<=word[12]\/)\d+
```

Example:

```
import re

text = 'https://www.pizza.com/word1/685185197419/word2/980054970331342/'
w1, w2 = re.findall('(?<=word[12]\/)\d+', text)
print(w1, w2, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
685185197419
980054970331342
```